# Is there a Dojo XPATH object?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath, dojo

Does anyone know if Dojo has a way of parsing XML objects using XPath?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I'll answer my own question... as it turns out Dojo has no support for parsing XML files using XPath.

Comment: So sad :-( I was hoping to use _something_ in dojo to parse through the dom document returned by the xml parser. I think they expect us to use the xmlStore instead. I feel your pain.